# Hibernate reporting differing data views

Tags: java, hibernate, report

How would be the easier way to map objets to retrieve multiple objects from a data table?

The scenario is that i have one record (for a third party system) where i log all info from an event (calling record). This calling record have many properties and i need to make it easy to manage.

picture the following table:

```
DATE    | origin | destine | user  | line in   | otherrandomdata ....
23/06   | ori1   | dest1  | user1 | line in 1 
23/06   | ori1   | dest1  | user1 | line in 1 
23/06   | ori1   | dest1  | user1 | line in 2 
23/06   | ori1   | dest1  | user2 | line in 1 
23/06   | ori1   | dest1  | user2 | line in 1 
23/06   | ori1   | dest1  | user2 | line in 2 
23/06   | ori1   | dest1  | user2 | line in 2 
23/06   | ori1   | dest1  | user2 | line in 2
```

I will need to create a report over this data, so would be nice to have a object with this struture:

Object Call

> > List Origin

Object Origin >List Destine

Object Destine >List user

Object User >List Line in

This columns are pure text, and if i just map one single object i would have several entries with "ori1" value, making it hard to iterate over a JSP (or another report source).

How could i make the described structure in my java?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with plain SQL if your DB supports [recursion](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html)

There is an [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23607020/how-can-i-sum-up-data-in-tree-like-structure-in-sql-from-children-to-parent) similar to yours, so you can check that too.

But a query like that would fetch a tremendous amount of data, so maybe it's better to build the tree dynamically. So you would fetch one level at a time, like in Windows Explorer folder structures.

This way you only fetch the data that the user is currently interested in, instead of retrieving all data even if he/she wouldn't use it anyway.

Comment: You mean, like get all Origins, query again for all destines of this origin, all users for this origin, etc? It wouldn't be worst then retrieve in a single sql? Your solution goes back to me setting all properties by hand? I would like hibernate to do so.